# Custom route, which doesn't display the Action in the link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to code a route in route config, which will give me tha chance to use this format `http://localhost:port/Account/1` rather than this `http://localhost:port/Accounts/Details/1`.

My code for this is the following :

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Account",
               url: "Account/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Details"}
            );
```

Sadly, this give me :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found
```

Any tips on how to make this work will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the `Action` method also.

Comment: public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return Content(blns[id]);
        }

Comment: What other routes are defined?

Comment: I discovered my problem. Obviously I had to place this route above the default route. Then it worked. (new to .net)